# angle inside a chordal quadrilateral

Tags: geometry

I am trying to solve this problem concerning this chordal quadrilateral. I'm supposed to find out $\beta$. Help is really needed since I study for an exam.
$\beta$ should be in dependency of the angle at $M_2$: $\beta= f(\text{angle at}\space M_2)$.
In the left bottom corner should be the point A, I was already playing around a bit finding out that the $\angle AM_2B$ is $90^\circ$ and that there are some angles same size because of the radius. But I don't get $\beta$. Can anyone please give me hints or show me one way of solving this problem? Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that opposite angles in an inscribed quadrilateral have sum $180^\circ$. It follows that $\beta=180^\circ-u$, where $u$ is the angle at $M_2$.

Comment: yes it´s not given , but beta should be in dependency of the anlge at m2: beta= f( anglem2)

Comment: have you got any idea how to solve??

Comment: If we do not know $u$, we have to know something else in order for $\beta$ to be determined. To see this, imagine that the radius of the little circle on the left is small, i.e. $M_2$ is close to $A$. The $\beta$ is small. If $M_2$ is further from $A$, then $\beta$ gets bigger. Do we know the radius of the smaller circle as compared to the bigger one?

Comment: the task doesnt say any numbers, it´s just looking for a description of the angle beta in dependency of the other angle my (the one at M2).

Comment: I was having trouble interpreting what you wrote. We have $\beta=180^\circ -u$, where $u$ is the angle at $M_2$. Or if you use radians, not degrees, then $\beta=\pi -u$.

Comment: ah okay so thats the solution? because of the shape of chordal quadrilateral all opposite angles are 180 degrees? and then it could say, your suggested solution? thank you! what would I have to do to get the codomain and the doain of definition for the function of beta?

Comment: Yes, that is the answer. If you want a genuine non-degenerate quadrilateral, the $0\lt \beta$. And $\beta$ can almost reach $90^\circ$. So $0\lt \beta\lt 90^\circ$, or, in terms of $u$, we have $90^\circ\lt u\lt 180^\circ$.

Comment: okay thank you for your help!!

Comment: You are welcome. Sorry it took so long, I had troubles with the wording.

Comment: it´s perfectly fine. I am just trying to translate from German to English too :-)